# PHP: case-insensitive preg_replace of a cyrillic string in UTF8

Tags: php, utf-8, internationalization, preg-replace

I have [a PHP 5.3 script](http://preferans.de/top.php) displaying users of my web site and would like to replace a certain Russian city (stored in UTF8 in PostgreSQL 8.4.7 database + CentOS 5.5/64 bits Linux) by its older name (it is an insider joke):

```
preg_replace('/Волгоград/iu', 'Сталинград', $city);
```

Unfortunately this only works for exact matches: **Волгоград**.

This does not work for other cases, like **ВОЛГОГРАД** or **волгоград**.

If I modify my source code to

```
preg_replace('/[Вв]олгоград/iu', 'Сталинград', $city);
```

then it will catch the 2nd case above.

Does anybody know what it going on and how to fix it (assuming I don't want to write **[Xx]** for *every* letter)?

Thank you!
Alex

**UPDATE:**

```
# rpm -qa|grep php
php53-bcmath-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-gd-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-common-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-pdo-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-mbstring-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-xml-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-cli-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-pgsql-5.3.3-1.el5

# rpm -qa|grep pcre
pcre-6.6-2.el5_1.7
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your issue with a PHP 5.3.3 (`PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)`):

```
$str1 = 'Волгоград';
$str2 = 'ВОЛГОГРАД';
$str3 = 'волгоград';

var_dump(preg_replace('/Волгоград/iu', 'Сталинград', $str1));
var_dump(preg_replace('/Волгоград/iu', 'Сталинград', $str2));
var_dump(preg_replace('/Волгоград/iu', 'Сталинград', $str3));
```

outputs

```
string(20) "Сталинград"
string(20) "Сталинград"
string(20) "Сталинград"
```

Which PCRE version is your PHP using? Check you `phpinfo()` for the `pcre`-section. That's the one on my system:

```
...
pcre

PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) Support => enabled
PCRE Library Version => 8.02 2010-03-19
...
```

Comment: "PCRE Library Version 6.6 06-Feb-2006", CentOS 5.5/64 bit with: 

php53-bcmath-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-gd-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-common-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-pdo-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-mbstring-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-xml-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-cli-5.3.3-1.el5
php53-pgsql-5.3.3-1.el5

Comment: Perhaps that's the problem... The PCRE version seems to be quite old.

Comment: Ok, that would be the usual problem of CentOS

Answer (score 4):

You can skip the regex, it worked for me in PHP 5.2.11 :)

```
$city = 'Unfortunately this only works for exact matches: Волгоград.

This does not work for other cases, like ВОЛГОГРАД or волгоград.';

echo str_ireplace('Волгоград', '[found]', $city);
```

#### Output

```
"Unfortunately this only works for exact matches: [found].

This does not work for other cases, like [found] or [found]."
```

This intrigued me, so [I asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458824/why-did-this-str-ireplace-work-on-a-non-ascii-string).

Comment: Unfortunately, str_ireplace('Волгоград', 'Сталинград', $city); has the same problem.

Comment: @Alexander What problem is that? Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

This one solved the problem:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.CP1251', 'rus_RUS.CP1251', 'Russian_Russia.1251');
```

Answer (score 2):

I copy+pasted your big `В`. It is indeed `U+D092`, not the normal latin `B`. But since they look so much alike: `ВB` I believe the russian letter is collated onto the Latin B of `U+0042`.

So either it's PHP preformatting it, or maybe PCRE is somewhat inexact there too. Test your `print PCRE_VERSION;` and have a look into the changelog.

Anyway, to evade the problem I would suggest you only use the lowercase letters. They are more likely to be distinct from the Latin alphabet.

```
preg_replace('/волгоград/iu', 'Сталинград', $city);
```

P.S.: Evil inside joke!

Comment: I wish I got the inside joke :)

Comment: My web site embeds the old Russian card game "Preferans" and when the player with the highest bid declares "6 spades" (i.e. going to take 6 tricks with the spades as trump; is the lowest possible bid in the game), then the 2 other players aren't allowed to show their cards to each other while defending. So they are playing "in the last stand" (like the Soviet troops while defending Stalingrad city against Germans).

Comment: I'm quite sure I have the Russian "В", and not the Latin "B" in my database. The replacement does work for the Russian "Волгоград"

Comment: @Alexander: It's probably the old PCRE library. `6.6` is five years old, and even the `7.x` version had some bugs like that. http://www.pcre.org/changelog.txt  -  Try to update that, libpcre is independent from PHP. I guess that's the source of your original problem. (Not that the database contains wrong characters.)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try: mb_eregi_replace
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-eregi-replace.php

> mb_eregi_replace — Replace regular expression with multibyte support ignoring case

Answer (score 1):

Works like a charm on my box...

```
<?php
    $city = 'Волгоград';
    var_dump(preg_match('/волгоград/ui', $city));
    var_dump(preg_match('/ВОЛГОГРАД/ui', $city));
    var_dump(preg_replace('/волгоград/ui', 'Сталинград', $city));
    var_dump(preg_replace('/ВОЛГОГРАД/ui', 'Сталинград', $city));
```

Output:

```
int 1
int 1
string 'Сталинград' (length=20)
string 'Сталинград' (length=20)
```

Are you sure that input data ($city) is in UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, but explicitly encoding the string to unicode may help:

```
preg_replace('/Волгоград/iu', utf8_encode('Сталинград'), $city);
```

Comment: Nope - no replacement happens at all

Answer (score 0):

Actually with PHP 5.2.x on windows the selected for a solved answer did not work for me.

I had to go through converting to Windows-1251 to make it work.

Here you go the example:

```
$new_content = preg_replace(iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', "/\bгъз\b/i"), iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', "YYYYYY"), iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', "ти си gyz gyz гъз ГЪЗ gyzgyz гЪз gyz"));
$new_content = iconv('Windows-1251', 'UTF-8', $new_content);
```

The example above will substitute successfully (case-insesitively) 'гъз' with YYYYYY and give you back the UTF-8 version.

Regards!

Comment: Note: I had a @setlocale(LC_ALL, "bg_BG.UTF-8");

Answer (score 0):

for those who support a huge legacy code base, struggling with charset & encoding issues, and without option to convert code charset - here's an answer:

```
//for 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.cp1251');  
//(or any other locale) to take effect, 
//you MUST generate system locale, i.e.

sudo su
#view supported locales
#less /usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
echo "ru_RU.cp1251 CP1251" >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
dpkg-reconfigure locales
exit

#and (for ubuntu/debian)

apt-get install php5-intl
```

while you can rewrite your regexp to use some utf tricks, convert your code to utf, it's not an option when you work with a huge codebase/database etc