# Why did this str_ireplace() work on a non ASCII string?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

**Note:** What I think I know is probably wrong, so please kindly fix my knowledge :)

---

[I just answered a question about UTF-8 and PHP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458396/php-case-insensitive-preg-replace-of-a-cyrillic-string-in-utf8/5458550#5458550)

I suggested using `str_ireplace('Волгоград', '', $a)`.

I didn't expect this to work, but it did.

I always thought PHP treated one byte as one character, hence why you need to use `mb_*` functions to get accurate results when using characters outside of ASCII range.

I assumed the Russian characters would take > 1 byte each.

I thought `str_replace()` would work because the bytes could be matched regardless of whether they are multibyte or not, as long as they are in order.

I thought `str_ireplace()` would *not* work because PHP wouldn't know how to map the non ASCII characters to their alternate case equivalent. But, it *did* work.

---

Where and how am I wrong? Give me as much information as you can :)

Comment: I would have proclaimed you have `mbstring.func_overload` enabled. But as per the docs it should not shadow `str_ireplace`. (Or it's just not documented.)

Comment: @mario I have `mbstring.func_overload` off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works by making the text lower case by passing it to the libc functions which are dependent on the locale settings; appropriate settings means that the text will lower case properly if the correct charset is used for the bytes.

Comment: PHP itself is not responsible for lower-casing the text used; it delegates to the libc (glibc, MSVCRT, etc.) which *does* know how to lower-case appropriately. That PHP sees it as only a sequence of bytes is mostly irrelevant, since *someone* in the chain knows what they're doing.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible explanation. The Unicode planes have similar attributes as the ISO-8859-1 range.

Converting an uppercase letter into lowercase just requires adding `0x20` for the ASCII range:

```
0x41   A
0x61   a
```

And -I did not bother to look it up- I think it's the same for the Latin-1 range in 0xC0-0xDF. And this coincidentally might work for the Russian letters in the Unicode range too:

```
d092d09ed09bd093d09ed093d0a0d090d094   ВОЛГОГРАД
d0b2d0bed0bbd0b3d0bed0b3d180d0b0d0b4   волгоград
```

The difference is just that 0x20 has been added on the bytes which were assumed to be L1 characters. So it's probably really just a locale setting.

Comment: +1 Thanks Mario, though I think I still have some learning to do. Were any of my statements above actually incorrect though?

Comment: But to know that it should leave the first byte of a UTF-8 multi-byte-sequence intact, it must be aware of the string actually being multi-byte. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @alex: It's a confuse topic. This can only be cleared up by inspecting the C source. I believe it's a perchance function here. The PHP string functions are unaware of the multibyteness, so either it's really a libc function as Ignacio said, or it is the accidential 0x20ing that worked here.

Comment: @Stefan: No indeed. The accident here is I assume that the 0xD0 unicode range prefix is left as is. It's only the 0x9x bytes which are transformed. The ISO-8859-1 lowercasing would work byte-wise, and skip the irrelavant. And here the second multibyte char just got ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Its the other way round: PHP does not treat every character as a byte, but it treats every byte as a character. So multiple characters are seen as multiple characters (and propably not that one you expect).

Comment: Thanks. That is what I meant to say :P