# How to find the word in the string, whether capitalized or small, if the text is not in English?

Tags: php, preg-match

if the characters are in engish language - no have problem, but if the language is bulgarian - not woking

example:

```
$text = "Още нещо"; 
if (preg_match("/още/", $text)) {
   echo "yes";
} else {
//print this
   echo "no";
}
```

Comment: have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458396/php-case-insensitive-preg-replace-of-a-cyrillic-string-in-utf8#answer-5458553), maybe usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 'i' modifier in a preg_match pattern to do a case-insensitive search.

So this should work for you (note the 'i' modifier in the pattern):

```
$text = "Още нещо"; 
if (preg_match("/още/i", $text)) {
   echo "yes";
} else {
//print this
   echo "no";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `/u` modifier for unicode and `/i` for case insensitive:

```
$text = "Още нещо"; 
if (preg_match("/още/ui", $text)) {
//            here __^^
   echo "yes";
} else {
   echo "no";
}
```